# Pervasive Kingroot app avoids uninstall

Tags: rooting, samsung, tablet, superuser, supersu

I managed to root my Verizon Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet with Kingroot, but I'd like to remove it and switch to using SuperSU (because of KingRoot's aggressive practices and somewhat shady reputation). Even after uninstalling it and deleting everything labelled kingroot or superuser in /system, I still get `Binary Occupied` from the SuperSU app.

I believe there is a hidden process somewhere monitoring attempts to delete it and replacing the binary. For example, in `system/usr` there is a directory called `iku` (kinguser?) which replaces itself immediately after being deleted. Similarly, in `system/xbin` there is `ku.sud` and `start_kusud.sh`, which I can delete but instantly reappear.

This may be a quirk of the Samsung system, or some kind of hidden or inaccessible process. I've followed numerous online tutorials, and tried to run the `Replace_Kingroot_With_SuperSU.zip` method, but to no avail. Anybody know of a workaround?

Edit: here is part of the stdout form a script I ran. Note where it says **operation not permitted**:

```
rm failed for /system/xbin/ku.sud, Operation not permitted
rm failed for /data/data/com.kingroot.RushRoot, No such file or directory
rm failed for /data/data-lib/com.kingroot.RushRoot, No such file or directory
rm failed for /data/data/com.kingroot.kinguser, Directory not empty
rm failed for /data/data/com.kingroot.master, No such file or directory
rm failed for /system/bin/.usr/.ku, Operation not permitted
rm failed for /system/bin/rt.sh, No such file or directory
rm failed for /system/bin/ddexe, Operation not permitted
```

Comment: you may need busybox for files and folder that persist to get romoved. also rm alone can't delete a folder that isn't empty

Comment: Do you have stock/custom ROM for your device? Is unlocking bootloader possible for your device?

Comment: I don't think so, it's a pretty tough device to root.

Comment: I believe it is showing operation not permitted because of immutable bit set on those files (protects the files from modification and deletion). You can remove that immutable bit but it requires busybox binary. The command is `busybox chattr -i FILE_PATH`. You can also try logcat command to see if anything shows up when you successfully delete those files (just to know what might be reinstalling them). // Also, you need to do `rm -rf`, not just `rm` if the target is in a directory and you're not running the command within that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it wrong I guess. There's a "safe" uninstall feature within Kingoroot app. This removes completely the app and the binaries from your device.

- Open the app
- Click the three dots upper right, find settings menu.
- Click "Remove Root".

Your device will be rebooted and root should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. This does completely remove root, however this way I'm unable to replace it with the SuperSU binary. Is there any way to insert the superuser binary before removing root, so I can still have root access after removing Kingroot?

Comment: SCH-I925 Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (Verizon 4G LTE), Android 4.1.2

Comment: I think u should just re-root by other means than kingoroot